# Problem when styling a child of a div element

Tags: css, css-selectors

i'm trying to create a login forum, while i'm styling the html i faced a problem when i had tried to style a child element of the  tag, here is my HTML:

```
    <div id="login">
            <h4>Enter your Email here</h4>
            <input type="text" id="loginmail" placeholder="Email">
            <h4>Enter your password over here</h4>
            <input type="password" id="loginpswd" placeholder="Password"> <br>
            <button id="submit">Log in</button>
    </div>
```

here is the CSS for the whole div:

```
#login
{
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #C5C5C7;
    text-align: center;
    width: 320px;
    height: 420px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 50px 20px;
}
```

So, now when i try to stylise the following IDs :

```
#loginmail, #loginpswd
{
    border: none;
}
```

nothing appears or changes, so basically i want to know where is the error,thanks guys !.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, in the [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pu76hc2j/) I made from your code it seems to work as expected, in that there are no borders on the elements you specify.

Comment: I've used some JavaScript and JQuery codes, but not for styling purposes,however, can this be the cause of the problem in a certain way ?

Comment: No one can answer that, unless you provide a [mcve] that actually show it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks I found the problem, a JS line that sets the CSS thank you very much for your help

Answer (score -1):

You missed a comma: `#loginmail, #loginpswd`

---

```css
#login
{
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #C5C5C7;
    text-align: center;
    width: 320px;
    height: 420px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 50px 20px;
}
#loginmail, #loginpswd
{
    border: none;
}
```

```html
   <div id="login">
            <h4>Enter your Email here</h4>
            <input type="text" id="loginmail" placeholder="Email">
            <h4>Enter your password over here</h4>
            <input type="password" id="loginpswd" placeholder="Password"> <br>
            <button id="submit">Log in</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks I found the problem, a JS line that sets the CSS thank you very much